# How to listen for requests and maintain "dialog" in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, http, httprequest, httpresponse

OK, I'm quite new to web developing and this is a bit difficult to define abstractly so I'll say exactly what I'm trying to do:

I have an asp.net website running on my server. I want to have other websites to have a button which redirects to a specific URL. This URL is determined during the creation (server side) of the other website. I want the other website to request that URL by supplying certain parameters. I'll create the URL accordingly and return a response which contains the URL.

To clarify: User browses other website, gets to page which is supposed to have said button, other website requests URL, supplies params, receives URL and creates page with button with URL received.

It's important to me that this works with any platform of "other" website. What is the simplest way to do this?

Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your best bet would be to create a web service that would be consumed by the other websites.

The MSDN site actually has a good overview and a couple of decent tutorials: A[SP.NET Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way would be to write a web service (WCF could be used, for example) which returns the said URL to the other web site. The "request for the URL" would just be a web service call from the other web site to your web service.